# Why multiply items in a ListView?

Tags: c#, xaml, listview, windows-phone-8

I created in the Loaded event of the main page, a List with some objects of my class "Regioni" and "Musei"

Then I added these items in a ListView, and SelectedItem event recovery the selected object and take it in a new page

```
private void Page_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {

        reg.Add(
            new Regioni
            {
                NomeRegione = "Toscana",
                NomeProvincia = "Firenze"
            });

        reg.Add(
            new Regioni
            {
                NomeRegione = "Toscana",
                NomeProvincia = "Prato"
            });

        var gruppi = reg.OrderBy(x => x.NomeRegione).GroupBy(x => x.NomeRegione);
        Museum.Source = gruppi;


        mus.Add(
           new Musei
           {
               NomeMuseo = "Galleria degli Uffizi",
               Paese = "Firenze",
               NumeroTel = "055294883",
               IndirizzoEmail = "mbac-sspsae-fi@beniculturali.it",
               PrezzoBiglietto = "8 € Intero, 4€ Ridotto\r\nGratuito inferiore 18 anni",
               Apertura = "Da martedì a domenica,\r\nore 8,15-18,50 Chiusura: Lunedi,Capodanno,Natale,1° Maggio.",
               IndirizzoWeb = "http://uffizi.firenze.it/",
               Immagine="Assets/Immagini/galleria-uffizi1.jpg",

               });
     }



private async void ListView_ItemClick_TuttiMusei(object sender, ItemClickEventArgs e)
        {
            var NuovoMuseo = (Musei)e.ClickedItem;
            this.Frame.Navigate(typeof(DettaglioMuseo), NuovoMuseo);
        }
```

Why when I insert the object into the new page "DettaglioMuseo", and go back on the main page, in the ListView I find the same items twice?

Answer (score 2):

This happens because the `Loaded`-event fires again and adds the items again.

So you should check if your `Regioni`s already exist before adding them:

```
private void Page_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    AddIfNotExists("Toscana", "Firenze");
    AddIfNotExists("Toscana", "Prato");

    var gruppi = ...
    ...
}

private void AddIfNotExists(string regione, string provincia)
{
    if (!reg.Any(r => r.NomeProvincia == regione && r.NomeProvincia == provincia))
    {
        reg.Add(new Regioni { NomeRegione = regione, NomeProvincia = provincia });
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, this works, but there is an alternative method? Sometimes it happens that in some items I post some properties, other objects in other properties, and so on. For each object does not insert all the properties (see the class museums). Is there an alternative method?

Comment: I see what you mean. You could implement equals in your classes (take a look [at this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/336aedhh%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) or [here in italian](https://msdn.microsoft.com/it-it/library/336aedhh%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)). With that implemented you can compare your objects like `if (nuovoMuseo == altroMuseo) { lista.Add(nuovoMuseo); }`.

Comment: Exist a method that is invoked only once when I open the page?